# Botkit, sending messages to rooms in Jabber

Tags: javascript, xmpp, botkit

I am trying to create a bot for jabber and it works fine if i send a message to a user e.g

```
bot.say(message = {
    text: 'hi',
    user: 'user@domain.com'
})
```

However when I am trying to do the same thing for a chat room it fails to do so. Do I need a specific JID for the chat room, if so where can I find it? 
I am currently trying with the following which fails.

```
bot.say(message = {
    text: 'hi',
    channel: 'roomName@domain.com'
})
```

This bot is written using botkit in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.say(message = {
            text: 'hi',
            user: 'j4wteam77161840418404@conference-1-standalonecluster.alpha-cup.cisco.com',
            group: true,
        });
```

Make sure you have add this bot into the room.
The room id is from room information of the pchat room. Remove im: when you copy room link to the code.

Comment: I have tried the following but unfortunately the message still does not appear in the chat. Maybe I misunderstood something. The bot is added to the room
            text: 'hi',
            user: 'room@conference-domain.com',
            group: true,